# C# rotate a pdf upon creation

Tags: c#, pdf, rotation

i'm working on method that create a delivery order pdf but recently i have been asked to add more columns in the array. As a result my array doesn't fit in Portrait size anymore so i'm trying to rotate my page in Landscape mode but i can't manage to make it work here is my code (some word have been modified/deleted for professional secret but it remain understandable. Thanks in advance

```
        public static void CreateDocument(String to)
    {

        System.Collections.Generic.List<Produit> listPro = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Produit>(MainWindow.produits);
        //listPro = ;
        // Create a new PDF document
        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument document = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();
        document.Info.Title = "Bon de livraison n°"+MainWindow.numOrder;
        int numpage = 1;
        decimal maxPerPage = 25.00M;
        Decimal numberPage = listPro.Count / maxPerPage;
        Console.WriteLine("nbr : "+ listPro.Count+ "/ 25 = "+ numberPage);
         numberPage = Math.Ceiling(numberPage);
        String watermark = "NE PAS DIFFUSER";
        while (1 == 1)
        {


            // Create an empty page
            PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
            page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape;
            page.Rotate = (page.Rotate - 90) % 360;

           // Get an XGraphics object for drawing watermark

            var gfx2 = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page, XGraphicsPdfPageOptions.Prepend);
            XFont fontWater = new XFont("Verdana", 40, XFontStyle.Bold);
            XSize size = gfx2.MeasureString(watermark, fontWater);

            // Define a rotation transformation at the center of the page
            gfx2.TranslateTransform(page.Width / 2, page.Height / 2);
            gfx2.RotateTransform(-Math.Atan(page.Height / page.Width) * 180 / Math.PI);
            gfx2.TranslateTransform(-page.Width / 2, -page.Height / 2);

            // Create a string format
            XStringFormat format = new XStringFormat();
            format.Alignment = XStringAlignment.Near;
            format.LineAlignment = XLineAlignment.Near;

            // Create a dimmed red brush
            XBrush brush = new XSolidBrush(XColor.FromArgb(128, 255, 0, 0));

            // Draw the string
            gfx2.DrawString(watermark, fontWater, brush,
              new XPoint((page.Width - size.Width) / 2, (page.Height - size.Height) / 2),
              format);
            gfx2.Dispose();

    // Get an XGraphics object for drawing the order

            XGraphics gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

            /*gfx.TranslateTransform(page.Width / 2, page.Height / 2);
            gfx.RotateTransform(-Math.Atan(page.Height / page.Width) *180 / Math.PI);
            gfx.TranslateTransform(-page.Width / 2, -page.Height / 2);*/

            // Create a font
            XFont font = new XFont("Verdana", 11, XFontStyle.Bold);
            XFont fontRegular = new XFont("Verdana", 8, XFontStyle.Regular);
            XFont fontMedium = new XFont("Verdana", 7, XFontStyle.Regular);
            XFont fontLittle = new XFont("Verdana", 6, XFontStyle.Regular);
            XFont fontRegularBold = new XFont("Verdana", 8, XFontStyle.Bold);




            // Draw the text
            gfx.DrawString("Bon de livraison", font, XBrushes.Black,
              new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, 100),
              XStringFormats.Center);
            gfx.DrawString(to, font, XBrushes.Black,
              new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, 130),
              XStringFormats.Center);
            gfx.DrawString("Produit à usage non thérapeutique", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black,
              new XRect(0, 0, page.Width, 160),
              XStringFormats.Center);
            int x, y;
            x = 40;
            y = 80;
            if (numpage == 1)
            {

                //  gfx.DrawString(to, font, XBrushes.Black, page.Width, 100);
               
                gfx.DrawString("Producteur : ", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x - 20, y - 50);
                gfx.DrawString("", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x - 10, y - 40);
                gfx.DrawString(" ", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x - 10, y - 30);
                gfx.DrawString("", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x - 10, y - 20);

                gfx.DrawString("N°BL", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x, y);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 110, y - 10, x + 170, y - 10);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 110, y + 4, x + 170, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 110, y - 10, x + 110, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 170, y - 10, x + 170, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawString(MainWindow.numOrder.ToString(), fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x + 113, y);



                x = 700;

                gfx.DrawString("to : ", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x - 30, y - 50);
                gfx.DrawString("", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x - 20, y - 40);
                gfx.DrawString("", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x - 20, y - 30);
                gfx.DrawString("", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x - 20, y - 20);



                gfx.DrawString("Technicien", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x - 20, y);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 60, y - 10, x + 120, y - 10);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 60, y + 4, x + 120, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 60, y - 10, x + 60, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 120, y - 10, x + 120, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawString(MainWindow.intervenant, fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x + 63, y);

                x = 40;
                y = y + 20;
                gfx.DrawString("Date d'envoi des Produits", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x, y);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 110, y - 10, x + 170, y - 10);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 110, y + 4, x + 170, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 110, y - 10, x + 110, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 170, y - 10, x + 170, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawString("10/03/2020", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x + 113, y);

                x = 700;
                gfx.DrawString("Nombre de produit", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x - 20, y);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 60, y - 10, x + 120, y - 10);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 60, y + 4, x + 120, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 60, y - 10, x + 60, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 120, y - 10, x + 120, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawString(listPro.Count + "", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x + 63, y);

                x = 40;

                y = y + 20;
                gfx.DrawString("Date d'envoi du BL", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x, y);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 110, y - 10, x + 170, y - 10);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 110, y + 4, x + 170, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 110, y - 10, x + 110, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x + 170, y - 10, x + 170, y + 4);
                gfx.DrawString("10/03/2020", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x + 113, y);

            }
            else
            {
                y = 100;
            }
            x = 50;

            y += 20;
            int ydebut = y;
            int xdebut = x;

            if (to == "Yes")
            {


                gfx.DrawString("", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x -= 38, y + 12);

                gfx.DrawString("Type", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 60, y + 12);

                gfx.DrawString("N°Lymphobank", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 30, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("Volume",fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x+=40,y+12);
                /*gfx.DrawString("IH et groupe sanguin", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 80, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("Age", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 90, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("Sexe", fontLittle, XBrushes.Black, x += 20, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("Résultats Qualification Biologique du Don", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 20, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("Blocage", fontLittle, XBrushes.Black, x += 370, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("NbrDon", fontLittle, XBrushes.Black, x += 30, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("Donneur Connu", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 30, y + 12);
                *///   gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, xdebut - 40, y, x, y);

            }

            if (to != "YES")
            {

                gfx.DrawString("Numéro Lymphobank", fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 3, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("Volume (ml)", fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 90, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("IH et groupe sanguin", fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 53, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("Age", fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 90, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("Sexe", fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 20, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("Résultats Qualification Biologique du Don", fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 25, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("Blocage", fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 370, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("Nbr Don", fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 40, y + 12);
                gfx.DrawString("Donneur Connu", fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 40, y + 12);
                

            }



            int Nproduit = 0;


            foreach (Produit pro in listPro)
            {

                Nproduit++; 

                y += 15;
                x = xdebut;
                // NumeroYES = prod.GetYES()
                //NumeroTypeProduit = prod.GetNumTypeYESProduit()
                // Sexe = "" + prod.GetSexe() + "", 
                //DateNaissance = "" + prod.GetDateNaissance() + "", 
                if (to == "YES")

                {
                    //gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x -= 40, y + 3, xdebut, y + 3);

                    gfx.DrawString(pro.GetYES(), fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 3, y + 12);
                    gfx.DrawString(pro.GetNumTypeYESProduit(), fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 60, y + 12);
                    gfx.DrawString(pro.ToString(), fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 30, y + 12);
                    gfx.DrawString(pro.GetVolume(), fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 30, y + 12);
                    /* gfx.DrawString(pro.GetGroupeSimple(pro.GetGroupeProduit()) + pro.GetGroupeNonElargie(pro.GetGroupeProduit()), fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 80, y + 12);
                     gfx.DrawString(pro.GetDateNaissance(), fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 90, y + 12);
                     gfx.DrawString("" + pro.GetSexe() + "", fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 20, y + 12);
                     gfx.DrawString(pro.GetResultatQBDTrans(), fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 20, y + 12);
                     gfx.DrawString(pro.GetBlocage(), fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 370, y + 12);


                     gfx.DrawString(pro.GetNombreDon(), fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 30, y + 12);
                     gfx.DrawString(pro.GetDonneurConnu(), fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, x += 30, y + 12);
                     gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, xdebut, y + 3, x += 80 - 3, y + 3);*/

                }
                else
                {

                    gfx.DrawString(pro.ToString(), fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 3, y + 12);
                    gfx.DrawString(pro.GetVolume(), fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 90, y + 12);
                    gfx.DrawString(pro.GetGroupeSimple(pro.GetGroupeProduit()) + pro.GetGroupeNonElargie(pro.GetGroupeProduit()), fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 53, y + 12);
                    gfx.DrawString(pro.GetDateNaissance(), fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 90, y + 12);
                    gfx.DrawString("" + pro.GetSexe() + "", fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 20, y + 12);
                    gfx.DrawString(pro.GetResultatQBDTrans(), fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 25, y + 12);
                    gfx.DrawString(pro.GetBlocage(), fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 370, y + 12);
                    gfx.DrawString(pro.GetNombreDon(), fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 40, y + 12);
                    gfx.DrawString(pro.GetDonneurConnu(), fontMedium, XBrushes.Black, x += 40, y + 12);
                    gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, xdebut, y + 3, x += 90 - 3, y + 3);

                }

                if (Nproduit == 25)
                {
                    break;
                }
                
            }

            listPro.RemoveRange(0, Nproduit);
            y += 15;
            x = xdebut;
            if (to == "YES")

            {
                /*gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x - 40, y + 3, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x -= 40, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 60, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 30, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 80, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 90, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 20, ydebut, x, y + 3);

                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 20, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 370, ydebut, x, y + 3);


                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 30, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 30, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 80, ydebut, x, y + 3);

                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, xdebut, y + 3, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, xdebut - 40, ydebut, x, ydebut);*/

            }
            else
            {

               /* gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 90, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 90, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 20, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 25, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 370, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 40, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 40, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, x += 90, ydebut, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, xdebut, y + 3, x, y + 3);
                gfx.DrawLine(XPens.Black, xdebut, ydebut, x, ydebut);
                */
                
            }
            gfx.DrawString("Page "+numpage + "/" + numberPage, fontRegular, XBrushes.Black, 750, 580);
            
            if (listPro.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nombre "+listPro.Count);
                numpage++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        // Save the document...
        string filename = "BonDeLivraison_" + to+".pdf";
        
        
        try
        {
            document.Save(filename);
            Console.WriteLine("Fichier sauvegarder : "+filename);
            //OUverture du document pur debug a enelever (mettre en commentaire)
            //Process.Start(filename);
            //decommenter pour que ca imprime automatiquement 
           RawPrinterHelper.SendFileToPrinter(MainWindow.imprimanteBon.getImprimanteText(),filename);
        }
        catch(Exception err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err+"", "Suppression du produit");

        }
    }
```

Comment: what does not work? What does the output look like?

Comment: Sorry it seem's my post is useless , PDFCreator make the delivery order looking like it's in Portrait format but after trying to print it , it is in Landscape. Sorry for the disturbance !